# jQuery, issue with mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover, slidetoggle

I have a span .test, when the mouse is over it, it slideToggle a div .frame.
As soon as the mouse leaves .frame, .frame slideToggle again.
It works perfectly but inside .frame I have some others div .qwerty, so when the mouse is over .qwerty, .frame slideToggle instead of staying display, but I don't get why because the divs .qwerty are inside .frame.

My code is:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.test', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var elWidth = el.width();
    $('body').append('<div class="frame"></div>');
    var frame = $('.frame:last');
    var posTop = el.offset().top;
    var posLeft = el.offset().left;
    el.hide();
    frame.hide().css({
        'left': posLeft,
        'top': posTop,
        'width':elWidth
    });
    frame.html('<div class="qwerty">qwerty</div><div class="qwerty">qwerty</div><div class="qwerty">qwerty</div>').slideToggle(150);
}).on('mouseout', '.frame', function() {
        var frame = $('.frame:last');
    frame.slideToggle(150, function() {
        frame.remove();
        $('.test').show();
    });
});
```

here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/dgJme/

for exemple if I fill out .frame by

```
qwerty<br>qwerty<br>qwerty
```

it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way `mouseover` is interpreted, technically, once your mouse is over another element it is no longer over that original element.
use `hover` instead..

```
 $('.test').hover(function() {
```

Unfortunately you'll have to amend your javascript for it to work properly with `.hover`

An alternative would be to check if the element you're currently on is a child of `.frame`

**Edit:** Although my answer is true, you've got an issue with appending the element to the `body` and hiding the `.test` element, so the element is no longer available to be focused on

This is what i would do http://jsfiddle.net/dgJme/1/ - basically append `.frame` to the `.test` element, that way you're hovered inside the `.test` element at all times, not matter how many children you have inside `.frame`

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I will apply your way, also I can delete the line "$('.test').show();" since I don't hide it anymore right? thanks again!!!!!

Comment: Yes exactly there's no need for the `.show` and `.hide` for `.test` - glad it helped.. mouseover is always a pain! I try to stay away from it if possible